# R - Check if File is Open/Closed and by which user

Tags: r, excel, file, xlsx

I have a document that is used by multiple people, and we have to continually check if the file is in use and by who.

I was wondering if there is anyway in R that I could obtain the status of an .xlsx file, if it is closed or open, and who has the file open.

I would then push this result to a HTML page which would refresh on a regular basis, this should then remove the need for the manual checking.

Comment: Are you in a Linux or Windows? Are you using php to manage and output? Instead of given direct access to the file, you could create a workspace that give access to the file. Inside the code you could use $clientData see here http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/client-data.html   then you could create a kind of log file each time user open the xlsx. Then you could read the log file in a kind of cron job whit PHP http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428. You could use php function stat() too. http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php

Comment: I will give it a shot and let you know, I am in a Windows environment, not currently using php just using R to create a flat HTML page.

Comment: As I understood you will have 1 file, that can be accessed by n users, and probably you will be the manager. I think you better explain that "I would then push this result to a HTML page which would refresh on a regular basis, this should then remove the need for the manual checking". What resullt? Math result from R script? Refresh on a regular basis-> For this you should use jquery, or pusher https://pusher.com/ . After refresh, retrieve what? User id? Last date file was changed? For this, maybe you should create a log file to store user id (that you could use stat()) and datetime to link

Answer (score 2):

Here is a starting point you might consider. This option is using C code you can compile in with R Cmd and call from R.

In a file "islocked.c" paste this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <share.h>

void testLock(int *locked, char **filename)
{
    FILE *stream;
    if( (stream = _fsopen( *filename, "wt", _SH_DENYWR )) != NULL ) {
        fclose( stream );
        *locked = 0;
    } else {
        *locked = 1;
    }
}
```

Open a command prompt (windows | find | 'cmd')
Change into the folder you saved the file above
From your command prompt c:\ type the following
    `"Program File\R\R-3.1.2\bin\r" CMD SHLIB islocked.c`
It shouldn't throw any errors or warnings and create a .o and .dll file as a result.

Now in R:

    `dyn.load('c:\pathtothe_c_file\islocked.dll')
    result->.C('testLock', islocked=as.integer(0), filename="d:\tools\r\test.dll")
    result$islocked
    [1] 1`

The dll is locked by R so this should return 1. Try the .o file and it should return 0. There is an API in Windows 7 and newer called IFileInUse which may return the process and possibly the user that has the file open that you might review if you need more information.

IsFileInUse API:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

A utility from Microsoft that runs on a command line you can shell to from R that may produce what you need, if you are able to install tools on the server:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx

Comment: Appreciate your solution. Is there a similar version on Linux?